MySQL procedure called from SQLAlchemy returns old results with each call
I have some MySQL procedures that work correctly when I run them directly in MySQL. But when I call them using SQLAlchemy, each time I call them, they return the new results with the results from the previous call. For example, the first call returns four rows. The second call should return five rows, but it returns nine -- five plus the prior four. This goes on  indefinitely. Here's one of the procedures:
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`service`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_get_filtered_items`(IN theArray varchar(255), IN searchText varchar(500))
BEGIN
    drop table if exists tmpFilteredItems; 
    if length(theArray) = 0 then
        create temporary table tmpFilteredItems
        as 
        (select * from vw_items
        where alltext like CONCAT('%', searchText, '%'));
    else
        call sp_get_code_table(theArray); -- generates tmpCodeTable from array.
        create temporary table tmpFilteredItems
        as
        (select * from vw_items 
            inner join tmpCodeTable on vw_items.instanceof = tmpCodeTable.codeCol
            where alltext like CONCAT('%', searchText, '%'));
    end if;
    select * from tmpFilteredItems;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

Here's my python code that makes the calls:
    def make_recordsets(self):
        raw_conn = self.eng.get_engine().raw_connection()

        try:
            # 1. create filtered results into temp table and retrieve
            cursor = raw_conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('sp_get_filtered_items', (self.instanceof_string, self.keyphrase,))
            for result in cursor.stored_results():
                tuples = result.fetchall()
                self.__items_to_dict(tuples)
            print(len(self.filtered_items))
            cursor.close()
            # 2. create properties list for follow-on searching; joins to temp table
            cursor = raw_conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('sp_get_filtered_props')
            for result in cursor.stored_results():
                tuples = result.fetchall()
                self.__props_to_dict(tuples)
            print(len(self.filtered_props))
            cursor.close()
            # 3. pick property with highest count for use in graphing link process.
            if not len(self.filtered_props) == 0:
                d = self.filtered_props[0] # get first row in rs, which has the highest count
                self.link_property = d['property']
                self.link_property_label = d['propertyLabel']
            # 4. create values list for use in graph creation; proc joins to temp table
            cursor = raw_conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('sp_get_filtered_values')
            for result in cursor.stored_results():
                tuples = result.fetchall()
                self.__values_to_dict(tuples)
            print(len(self.filtered_values))
            cursor.close()
            raw_conn.commit() # commit transactions to db
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.args)
            raw_conn.rollback()

        finally:
            raw_conn.close()
            self.eng.close()

Note that I am disposing of the engine connections in this example-- self.eng.close(), though that's not advised. Just trying to troubleshoot. Why would the DB hang onto the history of the results and return them as well?

Is it only the 1. call cursor.callproc('sp_get_filtered_items', that gives you these wrong results or any of the other ones ? And the self.__props_to_dict(tuples)  , self.filtered_items  etc are not keeping any unexpected state ?

Try wrapping with START TRANSACTION  / COMMIT so that each thing happens in the same transaction.  Without it, its possible for the update to happen and the select to happen and they are not in sync.

self.filtered_items etc/ were keeping the state of prior calls. Thanks for drawing my attention to that possibility. I'll post a solution.

In this case, I was inadvertently preserving the state of prior calls in properties of the class, e.g., self.filtered_items, which is a python list. I am using Flask for the front end, and it evidently is preserving the state of the class I use to retrieve the data between requests from the web browser. To solve this problem, I am just emptying the list in the property before it repopulates: self.filtered_items = [].
